# MySQLI Fetch Database Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have database table options, where am using it as a dedicated table to store information. I have never heard of this type of table query and have never tried it. I saw on WordPress database so thought to try my own.

**Here's database table**

[image]

**This is what am trying now**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM options WHERE option_flag = 'settings'";
var_dump( $db->FETCH_FIELD($sql) );
```

**This is inside my database class file $db**

```
public function FETCH_FIELD($sql){
    $this->results = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);       
$rows = mysqli_fetch_fields( $this->results );
    return $rows;
}
```

**The Problem**

When I var_dump the results, I don't see any database information.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to use mysqli_fetch_fields -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php and not mysqli_fetch_all -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to get an array that shows the query results, I would try this:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE option_flag = 'settings'");
$result = $stmt->fetch_all();
var_dump($result);
```

Of course, this works in procedural style, too:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
$stmt = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM options WHERE option_flag = 'settings'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($stmt);
var_dump($result);
```

Go to the php documentation to learn more about **[`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)**.